# Closed set that doesn't have the Baire property

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to do the following exercise from Hirsch's Differential topology :

> The subspace $X=\{f\in C_S^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}):supp f$ is compact $\}$ is closed but does not have the baire property.

I was able to see that this set is closed by proving that the complement is open. Now how do we prove that this not a baire space ? I mean I guess the idea would be to take dense open sets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is not dense in $X$, but I have no clue what dense open sets to consider, I don't even know any good dense open sets in $X$. Does anybody have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $C^0_{S}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})?$

Comment: Continuous functions in the strong topology, where we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as manifolds.

Comment: A subset $E$ of a topological space $X$ has the Baire property if there exists an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $E\Delta U$ is of first category. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire

Comment: Yeah but in the book he never defines it, and he defines being a baire space so I guess I am confused which one is supposed to be .

Comment: Since for a closed $F$ the symmetric difference $F \Delta \overset{\Large\circ}{F} = \partial F$ is always a a nowhere dense set, all closed sets have the property of Baire. Thus it's a safe bet that "is not a Baire space" was intended.